# Over-ride Distutils' Default Compiling Flags

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, distutils

How can I remove or change the default compiling flags that are used by "distutils" in a Python3 setup.py script?

Sometimes, there are compiler flags that I do not want distutils to use.

For this question, I am looking for an answer that will *either* force a set of compiler flags to be used (i.e., the ones I set), *or* remove flags that distutils wants to use.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
"""Distutils setup file for building C-based modules"""

from distutils.core import Extension, setup

__author__ = 'Devyn Collier Johnson'

__email__ = 'DevynCJohnson@Gmail.com'

__url__ = 'http://dcjtech.info/'

__copyright__ = 'LGPLv3'

__version__ = '2015.11.21'

COMPILE_ARGS = [
    '-std=c11',
    '-O3',
    '-Wl,-O3',
    '-gtoggle',
    '-g0',
    '-funroll-loops',
    '-pipe',
    '-ffunction-sections',
    '-fdata-sections',
    '-Wall',
    '-pedantic',
]


__classifiers__ = [
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Lesser General Public License v3 (LGPLv3)',
    'Operating System :: Android',
    'Operating System :: BeOS',
    'Operating System :: iOS',
    'Operating System :: MacOS',
    'Operating System :: Microsoft',
    'Operating System :: Other OS',
    'Operating System :: POSIX',
    'Operating System :: Unix',
    'Programming Language :: C',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only',
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries',
]


setup(
    name='chemistry',
    version=__version__,
    description='Chemistry-related Functions',
    author=__author__,
    author_email=__email__,
    maintainer=__author__,
    maintainer_email=__email__,
    url=__url__,
    license=__copyright__,
    classifiers=__classifiers__,
    ext_modules=[Extension(
        'chemistry',
        sources=['pychemistry.c', 'chemistry.c'],
        extra_compile_args=COMPILE_ARGS,
    )],
)
```

Current output from setup.py:

```
running build_ext
building 'chemistry' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c pychemistry.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pychemistry.o -std=c11 -O3 -Wl,-O3 -gtoggle -g0 -funroll-loops -pipe -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -pedantic
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c chemistry.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/chemistry.o -std=c11 -O3 -Wl,-O3 -gtoggle -g0 -funroll-loops -pipe -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -pedantic
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pychemistry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/chemistry.o -o /media/collier/PROGRAMMING/pybooster/lib/chemistry.cpython-34m.so
```

Comment: @kevin-guan , thanks for the edits, but the word "the" would be lowercase (not uppercase) because the word does not begin the sentence. Also, "i.e." is an abbreviation (of Latin words) that means "That is".

Comment: Oops, looks because Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit. Sorry about that :P

Comment: @KevinGuan , no problem. I was wondering why some important parts of my questions were missing. By the way, thanks for fixing the tags.

Comment: Okay :), however I don't know how to solve your problem. But if you'd like you can start a bounty tomorrow to get more attention.